# complex filter to find part of a string in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string I need to parse but im not sure how to go about without using lots of if statements and substrings. This is a sample of the string from a csv file that I split using "" because I couldn't use commas.

> Offset: 23,123 Length: 504  some more text some more text 213I
>
> Offset: 23,123 Length: 504  some more text
>
> Offset: 23,123 Length: 504
>
> Offset: 23 Length: 504,10  some more text some more text 213I

what I need is the numeric value after Length:

Any help is welcome. This type of of question has been asked before but not to satisfy my question. And I don't know how to use regex.

Comment: Might want to look into regex

Comment: Will you be trying *anything*?

Comment: `"And I don't know how to use regex."` -- well you might want to change that

Comment: My lack of experience has me at an in pass. I will look into regex but thought someone might shine a light for me

Comment: @MarkOShea the light I am shining _is_ regex

Comment: In the last example, would you return `504`, `504,10`, or `50410`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for that and tools like [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/ExpressoDownload.htm) to build and test regex'es

```
public static Regex regex = new Regex("Length:\\s*(\\d+)", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
static void Main()
{
    var testValue = "Offset: 23,123 Length: 504";
    var match = regex.Match(testValue);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Length is {match.Groups[1].Value}");
    }
}
```

Regex is `Length:\s*(\d+)` Explanation: `Length:` followed by 0 or more whitespaces, then need to capture group of 1 or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it without a regular expression:

1. Grab the `.Substring` starting with the end of the term you're searching for,
2. Use the Linq extension method `TakeWhile` to take characters while `char.IsDigit` is `true` for that character
3. Use `string.Concat` to join the characters back into a string again

Here's a sample method:

```
public static string GetNumberAfterKeyword(string input, string keyword)
{
    // Decide what you want to do if no keyword is found
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || !input.Contains(keyword)) return string.Empty;

    return string.Concat(input
        .Substring(input.IndexOf(keyword) + keyword.Length)
        .TakeWhile(char.IsDigit));
}
```

And a sample usage:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var sampleData = new List<string>
    {
        "Offset: 23,123 Length: 504 some more text some more text 213I",
        "Offset: 23,123 Length: 504 some more text",
        "Offset: 23,123 Length: 504",
        "Offset: 23 Length: 504,10 some more text some more text 213I"
    };

    var keyword = "Length: ";

    foreach (var sample in sampleData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetNumberAfterKeyword(sample, keyword));
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Another alternative using almost the same logic is to write a method that returns `true` if a number was found and which sets an `out` parameter to the value. This will save you from getting empty string, and will enable you to use the method in an `if` condition.

For example:

```
public static bool TryGetNumberAfterKeyword(string input, string keyword, out int result)
{
    bool foundResult = false;
    result = 0;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) && input.Contains(keyword))
    {
        foundResult = int.TryParse(string.Concat(input
            .Substring(input.IndexOf(keyword) + keyword.Length)
            .TakeWhile(char.IsDigit)), out result);
    }

    return foundResult;
}
```

And in use, with some additional data that has no keywords or no numbers:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var sampleData = new List<string>
    {
        "",
        "Hi",
        "No keyword",
        "Length: No number after length",
        "Length: ",
        "Offset: 23,123 Length: 504 some more text some more text 213I",
        "Offset: 23,123 Length: 504 some more text",
        "Offset: 23,123 Length: 504",
        "Offset: 23 Length: 504,10 some more text some more text 213I"
    };

    var keyword = "Length: ";

    foreach (var sample in sampleData)
    {
        int result;

        if (TryGetNumberAfterKeyword(sample, keyword, out result))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number or keyword is missing");
        }
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]